# how use one object dont introduce in phpclass?

Tags: php

http://s7.picofile.com/file/8244975134/Screenshot_9_.png
when use majic method if dont introduce object in class and use this object in this class for example in line 91 introduce this->student but student isnt in this class and phpstorm say field accessed via majic method I cant understand this scenario

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLMRX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that PHPStorm doesn't know that the field exists because you haven't declared it. In PHP, there is nothing wrong with this though, because there is a "magic method" called `__get()` that can decide if a property exists or not on the fly. PHPStorm is just warning you that the field is assumed to be accessible via this magic method.

In your case though you probably just want to declare the field.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the rest of the code. But maybe you miss the `__get()` function.
However there is another problem. In a double quoted string you have to use the `{` and `}`curly brackets around the object property (this is called [complex syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)):

```
$dummySqlPart = "WHERE Student_id={$this->StudentID} LIMIT 1";
```